# What is the difference between SecurityAttribute and CodeAccessSecurityAttribute?

Tags: .net, security

In creating a custom security attribute (declaratively demanding custom permissions in my case), what practical difference is there in inheriting from [`SecurityAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securityattribute.aspx) or [`CodeAccessSecurityAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.codeaccesssecurityattribute.aspx)?

Reflecting on the types, `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute` does not seem to extend `SecurityAttribute` in any meaningful way, so I can only assume the type is used by the CAS system, but that's code baked into the CLR, so I can't read into it.

All the examples of custom permissions inherit from `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute`, but without an explanation as to why. Indeed, the `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` inherits from `CodeAccsesSecurityAttribute`, despite not strictly being a CAS-related permission (as it has different semantics and references the current principal, not the permissions granted to the calling assembly).

My question is academic - I can just inherit from `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute` to progress - but I would like to know why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in your assumption that the `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute` type is used by the CLR itself.  This is essentially an AOP-style behaviour offered by the CLR, which will verify (and/or modify, as appropriate) permissions created by `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute` subtype instances at runtime.  The reason you can't use SecurityAttribute for your base class is that the CLR only scans for `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute` subtypes.  It will ignore other subtypes of `SecurityAttribute`.

As for why this is this case, I am unaware of any publicly available documentation.  However, it seems safe to assume that it's probably just an unfortunate byproduct of the .NET development history.  It's all too easy to imagine a scenario where non-CAS permissions were introduced late-ish in the design/development cycle of .NET 1.0, and support for these made it into the BCL but not into the CLR.  Given the small number of developers who actually create non-CAS permissions, "fixing" the CLR permission attribute detector has probably never been considered important enough to merit any serious attention in any subsequent .NET release cycle.

Comment: It's a shame that with all the recent changes to CAS, this hasn't been addressed.

Answer (score 1):

I would not advise using these attributes. Their functionality is too complicated and Microsoft itself admitted that. E.g. for Silverlight they are already obsolete: [System.Security.Permissions (Silverlight)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: The article made me chuckle; if they're obsolete in Silverlight, what replaces them to provide declarative security?

Comment: Maybe, nothing. Is it so necessary? There are OS restrictions and administartive actions.

Comment: I am principally concerned with access control. My application needs to make demands which are unique to the problem domain of the application and aren't in scope of the host environment. My intention was to build something which extended the existing security model (in the same vein as `PrinciplePermissionAttribute`).

Comment: @Programming Hero: There is an alternate authorization API recommended for Silverlight applications, using WCF RIA Services.  For an intro, see the series of posts at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/tags/authorization/.

Comment: @macropas: The transparency model used for Silverlight replaces explicit CAS permission use only.  For the types of authorizations usually implemented in non-CAS permissions, other alternatives are needed.  I have seen no documentation of the reason for the obsolescence of the types left in the System.Security.Permissions namespace in Silverlight, but the available documentation for the recommended alternate approaches for authorization suggest that the team is actively trying to encourage developers from avoiding client-only authorization.